# Pandas not getting data from other sheets

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, tkinter

I am trying to read and Excel, give a particular sheet's name and fetch the column headers. However, its only fetching the first sheet's column names and not the sheet's I am passing in.

Below is the code :

```
df = pd.read_excel(readDataFile(), sheet_names='Test1')
colHeaders=df.columns.tolist
print ("READ EXCEL SHEET : ", colHeaders)
```

`readDataFile()` returns the file path of the file.

Comment: `read_excel` does not have an option `sheet_names`. Did you mean `sheet_name`? Also, you did not call function `tolist` (you forgot the parentheses).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
df = pd.read_excel(readDataFile(), sheet_name='Test1')
colHeaders = list(df)
```

As previously told on the comments, you didn't add parentheses on the function call.

Comment: did that as well, it just returns the first sheet's data .

Answer (score 0):

The issue was sheet_name is not supported in older versions of PANDAS .
Upgraded the package , it worked fine .

Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

df = pd.read_excel(readDataFile(), sheet_names='Test1')
colHeaders=df.columns.tolist()

print ("READ EXCEL SHEET : ", colHeaders)

here you missed the paranthesis in tolist()

Comment: did that as well, it just returns the first sheet's data .